# Can't access external hard drives or thumb drives

Tags: 10.10, usb, mount, usb-drive, hard-drive

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 onto my laptop.  Everything is working great however USB devices such as thumb drives and external hard drives wont show up.  I have been looking around a bit and when I run `sudo fdisk -l` it displays this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00065684

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       29255   234983424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           29255       30402     9212929    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           29255       30402     9212928   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16026435072 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15283 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000df90d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       15283    15649776    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

It does seem to display my 16 gig thumb drive but other then seeing it here I cant access it to read and write files to it.  It does the same with my external hard drive.  I know those devices work as I have tried them on my other computer and they are working fine.

Also this is what is in fstab if this will help anyone:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

/dev/sdb1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1

/dev/sdb5       none            swap    sw                  0       0
```

Comment: have you tried manually mounting your drive? you can mount it using  "sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 <some directory>"

Answer (score 4):

The fstab seems broken.

It seems to define mount points for sdb, while your main disk is sda.

A quick fix could be changing all the sdb in fstab for sda and restart. But it's just a quick hack, the real solution should be using uuids for your drivers. Names like sd* can be changed if the BIOS reports the drivers in different order, sometimes just booting with some external device connected can cause it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really want to be the guy know for contributing nothing to this website than "please file a bug" but in this case I think it's a good idea. You have quite a good understanding of that's going on and have provided quite a lot of information.

Not sure if this affects anyone else, but hopefully this will be useful to the bug squashers to get this issue sorted for everyone.